# How to perform new operation on @RetryOnFailure by jcabi

Tags: spring, spring-aop, jcabi

Iam using jcabi-aspects to retry connection to my URL http://xxxxxx:8080/hello till the connection comes back.As you know @RetryOnFailure by jcabi has two fields attempts and delay.

I want to perform the operation like **attempts(12)=expiryTime(1 min=60000 millis)/delay(5 sec=5000 millis)** on jcabi @RetryOnFailure.How do i do this.The code snippet is as below.

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 12, delay = 5)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

Comment: Look at the Yegor's blog, there is a post about this feature : http://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/15/retry-java-method-on-exception.html I think it can help you

Comment: No actually i want to run the code which fails for every 5 seconds till 1 minute maximum i.e. **expiry time**.For my code expiry time is important !! How to incorporate expiry time in @RetryOnFailure is my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two annotations:

```
@Timeable(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTE, limit = 1)
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = Integer.MAX_VALUE, delay = 5)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

[`@RetryOnFailure`](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-retryonfailure.html) will retry forever, but [`@Timeable`](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-timeable.html) will stop it in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

The library you picked (`jcabi`) does not have this feature. But luckily the very handy RetryPolicies from Spring-Batch have been extracted (so you can use them alone, without the batching):

[Spring-Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry)

One of the many classes you could use from there is TimeoutRetryPolicy:

RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();

```
TimeoutRetryPolicy policy = new TimeoutRetryPolicy();
policy.setTimeout(30000L);

template.setRetryPolicy(policy);

Foo result = template.execute(new RetryCallback<Foo>() {

    public Foo doWithRetry(RetryContext context) {
        // Do stuff that might fail, e.g. webservice operation
        return result;
    }

});
```

The whole spring-retry project is very easy to use and full of features, like backOffPolicies, listeners, etc.